# Rails: Use a variable as a hash key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symbols

I've been trying to do this for the past 10 hours, but it's been useless.

For example:

```
Event.where(login_screen: Time.now-8.days ..Time.now)
```

I have an Event table and `login_screen` is one of the column names. I'm listing them in a drop-down menu and I'd like to take the event names as a variable. It's in the request params like this: `params[:segmentation][:first_event]`. When I tried to give it like:

```
Event.where(params[:segmentation][:first_event] Time.now-8.days ..Time.now)
```

...it didn't work. I tried to use `to_sym` but that didn't help either.

How can I use a variable as a symbol?

Another question:

What's the difference between `:hello` and `hello:` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's alternative syntax for ruby hashes with symbols as keys

```
Event.where(login_screen: Time.now-8.days ..Time.now)
```

is the same as

```
Event.where(:login_screen => Time.now-8.days ..Time.now)
```

So, if you store key in variable you need use 'hash rocket' syntax:

```
Event.where(params[:segmentation][:first_event] => Time.now-8.days ..Time.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

these are the different ways to pass arguments in where clause:--

```
User.where(["name = ? and email = ?", "Joe", "joe@example.com"])

User.where(["name = :name and email = :email", { name: "Joe", email: "joe@example.com" }])

User.where("name = :name and email = :email", { name: "Joe", email: "joe@example.com" })
```

**using hash:-**

```
User.where({ created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight })

User.where({ name: ["Alice", "Bob"]})

User.where({ name: "Joe", email: "joe@example.com" })
```